# "А почему ( ) никто не знает". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, спп

*Ира сегодня не пришла в школу. А почему **(?)** никто не знает.*

Нужна здесь запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужна запятая или тире. Без них получается простое вопросительное предложение: "Почему никто не знает?". На деле это сложноподчиненное предложение. Думаю, стандарт — запятая, а тире можно объяснить интонацией.

Примеры.

Вот живёт, живёт человек, а потом взял и помер, а почему, никто не знает. [И. Л. Солоневич. Две силы (1953)]  (Из Нацкопруса)

Но я люблю — за что, не знаю сам —//Её степей холодное молчанье...(Лермонтов)

Извините, конечно, но мы так всегда делаем, а почему — никто не знает! ([От мыльного пузыря до фантика: [сборник : для детей])](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=SfOubowglr4C&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=%22%D0%90%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%22&source=bl&ots=V_xHGUClWh&sig=qr8ee0pZjM-rik3IYQqcOfhjAKk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCj86Es6_XAhXSC-wKHQupDfEQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%90%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше поставить тире:

***Ира сегодня не пришла в школу. А почему -- никто не знает.***

Comment: Лучше поставить тире, а почему -- никто не знает.